# Can I use KeyBinding on KeyUp?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to use `KeyBinding` and execute the command on OnKeyUp in XAML?

If I want to bind the left-ALT key to execute my own command for menu access, because KeyBinding executes commands on OnKeyDown, I get some unwanted behaviour. For example, when tabbing out of the application with `Alt+Tab` the command will fire, and if the key is held down, the command is retriggered until the key is released.

I know the ALT is a modifier key, and a bit of a special case, but by waiting for OnKeyUp these problems would be avoided.

Comment: You can always just ignore the regular command and fire it on your own whenever you want. Just call CanExecute and Execute when necessary.

Comment: True, but I'm still hoping for a clean XAML solution, without involving code-behind. Prospects look bleak, though. :)

Comment: Partially clean XAML would be an attached behavior. But you would still need some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically use this [Attached Command Behavior](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) for hooking up Commands to Events

In your special case where you want to only execute the command when a specific key combination is pressed, I'd suggest hooking up both the `KeyUp` event and the `KeyUp` attached command.

In the regular `KeyUp` event, check if the key combination you want is being pressed and if not, mark the event as `Handled` so it doesn't get processed by the command as well

For example, this will only execute the bound command if the <kbd>A</kbd> key is pressed

```
<TextBox acb:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding TestCommand}"
         acb:CommandBehavior.Event="KeyUp"
         KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp"/>
```

and

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key != Key.A)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing it this way. I think it's a major flaw that KeyBinding is unable to trigger on KeyUp. I had to go for the e.SystemKey though, as e.Key does not make a difference between Alt and Alg Gr. :)