# Can't use KeyUp and KeyBinding on the same control

Tags: wpf, xaml, events

I've come across some unusual behaviour, I'd like to use a `KeyBinding` to bind the `Enter` key to a command in my view model, but I also want to subscribe to the `KeyUp` event on the control in the view's code-behind. Here's an example:

```
<TextBox Name="txtCustomBarcode"
         KeyUp="CustomBarcode_KeyUp">
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ScanBarcodeCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtCustomBarcode}" 
                        Key="Enter"/>
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>
```

If I use this method, then **only the command** will get executed, the code-behind event gets ignored. If I remove the `KeyBinding`, then the `KeyUp` event gets called as expected.

Is there a way I can use a `KeyBinding` **and** a `KeyUp` event on the same control?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11101557/563088

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible because the control would need to have two different data context and as far as I know it isn't possible to do.

EDIT: Actually upon further reading, you may be able to do something like this: 
[Multiple dataContext for one control - MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498890/multiple-datacontext-for-one-control-mvvm)